# Swift - How to retrieve multiple images at once (GCD)?

Tags: ios, swift, image, grand-central-dispatch

Let me give you some insight on my application itself.

To put it in short, I am creating a social-networking app. Each post consists of an *image*, *profile picture*, and *caption*. Each post exists in my MySQL database. I am using my own framework to retrieve each post. However, once I retrieve each post I still have to retrieve the *profile picture* and *image* using the URLs which I retrieved from the database. **I would like to retrieve all images at once rather than running in sequential order.**

As of now, there are about 5 posts in the database. Loading the necessary images for **one** post takes about 4 seconds. So right now I am loading the images for one post then retrieving the next in sequential order. So this whole process takes around 20 seconds. So say have 50 posts then it will take an extremely long time to load all the posts. I have some knowledge of *GCD (grand-dispatch-queues)* however I don't know how to implement it in my app.

Here is my code for retrieving my posts and images:

```
ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.retrievePosts(UserInformationInstance.SCHOOL) {
        (result: AnyObject) in
        if let posts = result as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            print("Retrieved \(posts.count) posts.")
            for post in posts {
                let postIDCurrent = post["id"] as? Int
                var UPVOTES = 0;
                var UPVOTED: Bool!
                var query = ""

                if let profilePictureCurrent = post["profile_picture"] {
                    // Loading profile picture image

                    let url = NSURL(string: profilePictureCurrent as! String)
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    UserInformationInstance.postsProfilePictures.append(image!)
                    print("added profile pic")
                } else {
                    print("error")
                }
                if let postPictureCurrent = post["image"] {
                    if (postPictureCurrent as! String != "") {
                    // Loading image associated with post

                    let url = NSURL(string: postPictureCurrent as! String)
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    let imageArray: [AnyObject] = [postIDCurrent!, image!]
                    UserInformationInstance.postsImages.append(imageArray)
                    print("added image pic")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error")
                }
                UserInformationInstance.POSTS.append(post)
            }
        } else {
            self.loadSearchUsers()
        }
    }
```

**So my question is, how can I retrieve all the images at the same time instead of retrieving one after the other?**

It would be great if someone could give an explanation as well as some code :)

Comment: Is my understanding correct? You are getting the images from remote service?

Comment: @Melifaro Yes, I am getting the images from my AWS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to revise your approach. If your server is fine - it's not busy and well reachable, so that resources downloading is limited by device network adapter bandwidth (X mbps), then it does not matter how you downloading images - concurrently or sequently.

Let me show this. Downloading time of 10 files with size Y mb simultaneously is equal to downloading time of one file, but in this case the downloading speed will be 10 times slower per file:

```
X/10 - downloading speed per one file
Time = Amount / Speed
T = Y / (X/10) = 10 * Y / X
```

Now if your are downloading sequently:

```
T = 10 * (Y / X) = 10 * Y / X
```

I would recommend to show posts immediately once you retrived them from the storage, then you need to start image downloading asynchronously and set image once that's downloaded. That's the best practice in the industry, consider Facebook, Twitter, Instagram apps.

Comment: Hi, sorry for responding so late. Anyways, so I want to make sure I get what you are saying. First let me thank you for the clear explanation on downloading speeds. So would this be a good system for downloading images: the first time the user logs in, load all the posts and store them on the device; the next time the user logs in, load all the NEW posts and load the old ones from storage?

Comment: That's a good idea to put posts into the DB once they are loaded. I would also recommend to store downloaded images in some "file storage" folder, so that they both (posts and images) could be reused. The main idea of the post, is to separate posts downloading (json, xml, or whatever format your server uses) and images downloading. You can show something worth to user even if you have not downloaded images.